# addEventListener (show/hide)

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, getelementbyid, addeventlistener

I want do a toggle with a button to show and hide a tag(div). So, buttom(toggle) --> to div(show/hide).

```
    window.onload = function(){
      var button = document.getElementById('button');     
    function show(event){
      event.target.classList.toggle('hide');
    }       
      button.addEventListener('click', show, false);     
    }
```

Because in jQuery is so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $( "#button" ).click(function(){
  $( "div" ).toggle( "slow" );
   });

});
```

But in JavaScript?

Comment: Is that what you are trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/a9hopcqm/ ?

Answer (score 2):

I do not completely understand your question but I suspect your trouble is with targeting the div which should be hidden or shown.

To do this with jQuery:

HTML

```
<button class="toggle">Toggle</button>
<div class="text">Hello</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button.toggle").click(function(){
        $("text").toggle();
    });
}
```

Comment: You know JavaScript, because jQuery all is more easy, thanks.